# Convert string to binary in Go

Tags: string, go, binary

How do you convert a string to its binary representation in Go?

Example:

> Input: "A"
>
> Output: "01000001"

In my testing, `fmt.Sprintf("%b", 75)` only works on integers.

Answer (score 6):

Cast the 1-character string to a byte in order to get its numerical representation.

```
s := "A"
st := fmt.Sprintf("%08b", byte(s[0]))
fmt.Println(st)

Output:  "01000001"
```

(Bear in mind code "%b" (without number in between) causes leading zeros in output to be dropped.)

Answer (score 5):

You have to iterate over the runes of the string:

```
func toBinaryRunes(s string) string {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    for _, runeValue := range s {
        fmt.Fprintf(&buffer, "%b", runeValue)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", buffer.Bytes())
}
```

Or over the bytes:

```
func toBinaryBytes(s string) string {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        fmt.Fprintf(&buffer, "%b", s[i])
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", buffer.Bytes())
}
```

Live playground:

http://play.golang.org/p/MXZ1Y17xWa