# How Convert StringText To Binary And Conversely Using Go

Tags: algorithm, go, hash, rune

i want Convert `Text`(type=`String`) To `Binary`(type=`String`) And `Conversely` Using Go

some userfull link :
[Golang: How to convert String to binary representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349071/golang-how-to-convert-string-to-binary-representation/37350639) & 
[Convert string to binary in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685687/convert-string-to-binary-in-go)

but i need another.

i want example convert a text like `hello` to `binary`. and next can convert then binary to first text(`hello`).

```
var hash_text := hash("hello")//example return *****
var unhash_text := unhash(hash_text);//return hello
```

like this gist.github.com/hutt/8978333 (using php)

also `speed` for me is `importamt`.

Comment: what do you mean by "binary"? Your example of changing a string to `*****` and magically transforming it back doesn't make any sense

Comment: like this https://gist.github.com/hutt/8978333 (using php)

Comment: I still don't understand. A string is just a slice of bytes, and can be converted  directly to `[]byte`, it already is as "binary" as you can get. Please show exactly the output you expect.

Comment: `1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111` == `hello` in this php source

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/5I2DIWisKF?

Comment: how store %b without [ and ] character? and also delete `\s`(space) ? not have optional then auto delete? replace may not good for speed.

Comment: i think this is not good. i want a function then for all char of text and convert every char. then i can change , and add more hash on them. and speed important.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? This isn't a "hash" as you've called it here, it's simply changing the string representation, so you're going to be limited by manipulating strings.

Comment: yes , is right. but next i want hash them....

Comment: i want two function like [PHP Script](http://gist.github.com/hutt/8978333) for Go.

Comment: `<?php echo decbin(ord("c")); ?>` and `<?php echo chr(bindec("1101000")); ?>` how do this in GO?

Comment: FYI, there's absolutely no useful reason to change the string representation like this for hashing, and looks like a gross misunderstanding of how to securely hash a string. Is this what you want to do? https://play.golang.org/p/SnyWzJlTTF

Comment: woow..tank you.very tank from you.

Comment: but not work for utf-8 text!! how fix?

Comment: You need to _not_ try to use it as utf8, and index the string bytes directly. I'll post it so you can see it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert each byte individually to its base 2 representation. You can use `strconv.ParseUint` to convert the base2 back to bytes.

```
func stringToBase2(s string) string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        fmt.Fprintf(&buf, "%08b", s[i])
    }
    return buf.String()
}

func base2ToString(s string) string {
    var out []byte
    for i := 0; i+8 <= len(s); i += 8 {
        b, err := strconv.ParseUint(s[i:i+8], 2, 8)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        out = append(out, byte(b))
    }
    return string(out)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/cLvoPHZ-hH

Comment: `need try,catch to not show error if not binary`.. example : `fmt.Println(base2ToString("jdfgidjfigjdfidfg"))` how fix this? show error : `panic: strconv.ParseUint: parsing "jdfgidjf": invalid syntax`??? how fix?

Comment: I purposely made it panic on invalid input. If you want to catch all errors, you are free to do so.

Comment: instead of `panic`, return the error and handle it. Have you gone over the basics of Go? Maybe take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/)

Comment: @LovePython: `adler32` is a checksum, you can't "decode" it. Do you mean [`adler32.Checksum`](https://godoc.org/hash/adler32#Checksum)? Please take some time to learn the basics and how to check the documentation.

Comment: oh, Ok. i have a text(number). how can minify this? what hash is better and minify?

Comment: and also about `stringToBase2()` you sure then all character utf-8 max have `%08b` 8 bit/byte?

Comment: @LovePython: stringToBase2 doesn't have anything to do with utf8. A byte is 8 bits, and you're converting the string's bytes into a base 2 representation. Again, this is a pointless exercise, and amounts only to a minor obfuscation of some sort.

Comment: @LovePython: what do you mean by "minify"? Minify implies compression, but a hash is by definition a lossy one-way transformation.

Comment: yes. now i have a string , and i want compression them. what algorithm good for compression?